# SQL Update me da error de conversión de varchar a datetime pero no estoy actualizando una fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo el siguiente update (excesivamente simple):

```
UPDATE Articulos
SET ComentarioArticulo = 'prueba'
WHERE CodigoEmpresa=1000 And CodigoArticulo='2AT004S'
GO
```

Y me da el error:

```
La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.
```

El tema es que no entiendo que está pasando ya que ninguno de los tres campos a los que referencio es un datetime:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo unico que creo que puede provocar el error es que entre todos los datos de la tabla Articulos si que hay algunos que son datetime pero eso no debería afectar ¿no?

Comment: ¿Has revisado si la tabla tiene algún trigger?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Efectivamente buen señor, no había mirado y tiene un trigger, muchas gracias